# adding a script on Gatsby with setPostBodyComponents only on certain pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Is it possible to render a script that has been inserted within the body tag (using setPostBodyComponents) only in certain pages other than all of them ?

Any ideas if this would be possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [`gatsby-ssr-js` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#onRenderBody), `onRenderBody` exposes a bunch of `props` where there's a `pathname`.

> `pathname` {string}
>
> The pathname of the page currently being rendered.

That said, you can try something like:

```
const React = require("react")

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents, pathname }) => {
   const SCRIPT_PAGES = ['/page-1', '/page-2'];

   if(SCRIPT_PAGES.includes(pathname)){
      setPostBodyComponents([
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:`your script here`}} />,
    ]);
  }
};
```

In that case, your `SCRIPT_PAGES` will hold the pages where the script will be inserted. Using that approach, you can tweak it as you want.